# $rename - Rename a Field in an Embedded Document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to change the value in the embedded document key, but the update does not happen.
I tried to update the Key in the embedded document by using the following command in Mongo Shell :

```
db.TestCollection.update( {"_id: "1235647898eee4475"}, { $rename: { "welcome.ext.http://google&46;com/api/ext/extdisplay": "welcome.ext.http://google.com/api/ext/extdisplay" } } )
```

I expected `$rename` to replace `&46`; in `Key` with a `.` in the embedded Collection document.

Can somebody help to rename them in the embedded document, and  perform some bulk update for 100k documents?

Comment: Is this "welcome.ext.http://google&46;com/api/ext/extdisplay" a key/field name or a value?

Comment: Mongo doesnot support such operations in straight way. If its just one time task, you can iterate over the records and unset the wrong data and add new data.

Comment: @ersnh can you please explain how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can not have a dot (.) in a key name in MongoDB. I'm assuming that your current structure is like

```
{
  "welcome" : {
    "ext" : {
      "http://google&46;com/api/ext/extdisplay" : "some value"
    }
  }
}
```

and you want to change it to

```
{
  "welcome" : {
    "ext" : {
      "http://google.com/api/ext/extdisplay" : "some value"
    }
  }
}
```

If this is your requirement, then sorry its not supported in MongoDB